# Auto-Update Messaging in PHP without using set interval function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am trying to build a messaging environment in PHP and stuck with some issues. 
I am facing difficulties in auto-update of user online-list and messages. I want to auto update the user-list without need of reloading page again and again as it is going to put load on our server. same problem is in messaging. I want messages to get auto updated but don't want to put load on my servers with multiple hits using set interval function. So, Is there any robust and feasible method or theory that could help me out here.

Thanks in advance to those who are going to put any effort here.

Comment: AJAX, or in your case even better: WebSockets

Comment: *Thanks in advance to those who are going to put any effort here.* - Please put more effort in your question and read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Comment: Hi Script, I am new here, is there something wrong in my question, Or you are being sarcastic?

Comment: @technicalbird no sarcasm at all. Please show us your written code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax or it is better to use `websockets` such as **[socket.io](https://socket.io/)** or **[pusher](https://pusher.com/)**.

**For more references:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

https://www.websocket.org/aboutwebsocket.html

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

**Anyhow,**
Edit your question, so more developers will help you to your problem. Show some code/references etc. [Learn more...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

- Ajax, but you don't want use it (through setInterval)
- Using web sockets with node js as web server

If you choose node, here there is a simple example: https://medium.com/@martin.sikora/node-js-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial-2def3a841b61

Comment: [You can use WebSockets with PHP...](http://socketo.me/) No need for the Node.JS .